# ExtJs 4 - Drag and Drop in the same grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How do you do reordering of grid rows in ExtJs 4 by drag and drop? And is it possible? I see  there is an example for drag and drop grid rows between 2 grids in the ExtJs examples page, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to use this and make it work in one grid only.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, so I just figured it out. It was quite simple actually... All I needed was to simply add

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop'
}
```

to the grid's viewConfig and it works just fine.

Please don't down-rate this question. I'm sorry I didn't search more for the answer before posting the question here and had to answer my own question, but hope the answer will help someone else if searching for a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',dragText:'Reorder Rows'
},
// to save position  
listeners:{
    drop:function(){
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:'url-to-save-position',
            params:{
                value:Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(grid.getStore().data.items, 'data'))
            }
        })
    }
}
```